# Is it illegal or against the ToS to have two facebook accounts?

Tags: internet, contract-law, terms-of-service

When creating an online account, you often agree to the terms of service (ToS). Often in the ToS it says only one person can have one account. Does this mean if someone creates another account they are breaking the law?

In particular I'm interested in Facebook. In their [terms](https://www.facebook.com/terms) they have

> You may also want to review the following documents, which provide
>   additional information about your use of Facebook: ...
>
> [Community Standards][2]: These guidelines outline our expectations
>   regarding the content you post to Facebook and your activity on
>   Facebook.

I found [this page](https://www.facebook.com/help/975828035803295?helpref=uf_permalink) which explicitly states:

> It's against the Facebook Community Standards to maintain more than
>   one personal account.

So it's against Community Standards, but is it against the ToS?

I'm too new to post more than 2 links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook [TOS](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) 4(2) says "You will not create more than one personal account".

Comment: What does it mean by personal?

Comment: This would be as opposed to a business or "special interest" account: i.e. an account about an individual. It's not clear to me that there is a distinction in accounts, but this allows them to create a distinction without blocking people with personal accounts from opening a business account.